# Remove inner vertical borders in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to remove the inner borders in a JTable.
I've researched the question and found that I could remove all vertical borders
so the JTable would look like:

```
---------------------            +-------+-------+-------+
(0,0)   (0,1)   (0,2)            | (0,0) | (0,1) | (0,2) |
---------------------            +-------+-------+-------+
(1,0)   (1,1)   (1,2) instead of | (1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2) |
---------------------            +-------+-------+-------+
(2,0)   (2,1)   (2,2)            | (2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2) |
---------------------            +-------+-------+-------+
```

However what I want is this:

```
+-----------------------+
| (0,0)   (0,1)   (0,2) |
+-----------------------+
| (1,0)   (1,1)   (1,2) |
+-----------------------+
| (2,0)   (2,1)   (2,2) |
+-----------------------+
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't think of a neat way to solve this that does not involve overriding some internal `paint()` call, which could get messy. So here is a less elegant solution: disable the vertical lines and then add a line border of the apropiate color.

```
table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
Color lineColor = new Color(122, 138, 153); //(122, 138, 153) is the RGB color of the lines, at least in my computer/OS/L&F...
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(lineColor));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend `BasicTableUI` and override paintGrid to modify how the grids are painted.